# Add class on click then remove a class when clicking outside the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried all the ways from the answers here, but have not worked.
So far I have done:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sb-search").click(function(){
          $(".sb-search").addClass("sb-search-open");
          $("body").click(function(){
              $(".sb-search").hasClass("sb-search-open");
              $(this).removeClass("sb-search-open");
          });
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
    <form autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
        <input class="sb-search-input" type="search" value="" name="s" id="s">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
        <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to remove the `.sb-search-open` class after clicked outside the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sb-search").click(function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();
          $(".sb-search").addClass("sb-search-open");

      });
      $("body").click(function(){
              $(".sb-search").removeClass("sb-search-open");
              console.log('body')
       });
  });
});
```

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
    <form autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
        <input class="sb-search-input" type="search" value="" name="s" id="s">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
        <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

First remove click listener on body out side the input click listener.
in input click listener add e.stopPropagation() to stop bubbling of event

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#sb-search").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           e.stopPropagation();
          $(".sb-search").addClass("sb-search-open");

      });
      $("body").click(function(){
              $(".sb-search").removeClass("sb-search-open");
       });
  });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work sir, and can't execute search input

Comment: @SamberPelix add some css on body try now

Comment: Yes I can add and remove the class now, but I can't execute the search input.

Comment: Thank you Sir! It's works now. I removed `e.preventDefault();`.